# Issue with Jupyter Object_Detection_Tutorial - DLL load failed while importing win32api

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have been trying to get a Jupyter object detection tutorial to run but for some reason, when the left hand side should go from In[] and switch to In[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1tV3.png), it stays as In[0]. I assume this means the code isn't actually running. The top of the page also says there is a Kernel Error and when I click this, the following code is displayed:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1703, in _execute
result = await result
File "c:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
File "c:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 69, in post
model = yield maybe_future(
File "c:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
value = future.result()
File "c:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
File "c:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
File "c:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
value = future.result()
File "c:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
File "c:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 100, in start_kernel_for_session
kernel_id = yield maybe_future(
File "c:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
value = future.result()
File "c:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
yielded = next(result)
File "c:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel
super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
File "c:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 158, in start_kernel
km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
File "c:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 301, in start_kernel
kernel_cmd, kw = self.pre_start_kernel(**kw)
File "c:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 248, in pre_start_kernel
self.write_connection_file()
File "c:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 468, in write_connection_file
self.connection_file, cfg = write_connection_file(self.connection_file,
File "c:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 138, in write_connection_file
with secure_write(fname) as f:
File "c:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\contextlib.py", line 113, in **enter**
return next(self.gen)
File "c:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 435, in secure_write
win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)
File "c:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 361, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
import win32api

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: The specified module could not be found.

I am not sure why there is an import error. For reference, I have downloaded CUDA 10.1, cuDNN 7.6.5, anaconda for python 3.6, and TensorFlow 2.0.0. Please let me know how I can fix this to get the Jupyter code to run.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Then I rebooted and it worked fine.